# some of stm32 binaries cannot run because the first 8 bytes(isr_vector and entry points) of binaries is incorrect. but don't know how to solve

Tags: arm, stm32, bootloader, isr

When I compile stm32 projects(using cmake), some large project cannot run but other small ones can(**with exactly same configure**)! 
And after one day debugging, I believe the problem is at the first 2 words(isr_vector address and entry point address is incorrect)

**Description:**

At first I have one bootloader(binary 11k) and one project(130k), all can run perfectly with keils 5(windows). And I'm trying to move to linux, I use CMake reconstruct the project, replace startup.s/asm for gnuc, giving gcc ldscript(sections and memory), Now the bootloader can run from 0x8000000. But the project cannot run from either 0x8000000 or 0x80080000(certainly I changed isr, ldscripth and jlink script according to address);

**Problem:**

When compiling bootloader(or any thing can run) the first to words of binary looks like:

```
00 00 01 20  0d 1c 00 08 //0x20010000 & 0x08001c0d
```

which means isr_vecotr is placed in ram and programs main at 0x08001c0d. and when debugging the program runs at 0x08001c0d.

But, when I compile Project, the first words looks like:

```
5c 84 02 08 00 00 00 20  //0x0800845c & 0x20000000
```

And when I debuging using Ozone, the program runs at 0x20000000 and every thing is unbelievable.

**Configure:**

*Toolchain File:*

```
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME               Generic)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR          arm)
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION            1)
set(CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING            1)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_WORKS          1)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "arm-none-eabi-g++")
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER   "arm-none-eabi-gcc")
set(CMAKE_ASM_COMPILER "arm-none-eabi-gcc")

add_definitions(-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release)
set(COMMON_FLAGS "-DSTM32F10X_HD -DUSE_STDPERIPH_DRIVER -DHSE_VALUE=8000000 --specs=nosys.specs -mfloat-abi=soft -MMD -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb -mthumb-interwork -Wall")
```

*Ldscript:* both is same:(I just want to run without bootloader first, at 0x8000000)

```
MEMORY
{
  RAM (xrw) : ORIGIN =  0x20000000, LENGTH = 64K
  FLASH (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x08000000, LENGTH = 512K
  CCMRAM (xrw) : ORIGIN = 0x00000000, LENGTH = 0
}
```

---

```
__stack = ORIGIN(RAM) + LENGTH(RAM);
_estack = __stack;  /* STM specific definition */
__Main_Stack_Size = 1024 ;
PROVIDE ( _Main_Stack_Size = __Main_Stack_Size ) ;
__Main_Stack_Limit = __stack  - __Main_Stack_Size ;
PROVIDE ( _Main_Stack_Limit = __Main_Stack_Limit ) ;
_Minimum_Stack_Size = 256 ;
PROVIDE ( _Heap_Begin = _end_noinit ) ;
PROVIDE ( _Heap_Limit = __stack - __Main_Stack_Size ) ;
ENTRY(_start)
SECTIONS
{
  .isr_vector : ALIGN(4)
  {
    FILL(0xFF)
    __vectors_start = ABSOLUTE(.) ;
    __vectors_start__ = ABSOLUTE(.) ; /* STM specific definition */
    KEEP(*(.isr_vector))        /* Interrupt vectors */
    KEEP(*(.cfmconfig))         /* Freescale configuration words */   
    *(.after_vectors .after_vectors.*)  /* Startup code and ISR */
  } >FLASH

  .inits : ALIGN(4)
  { .........bulabulabula}.....
```

Here I just wanna say I do place the isrvector at beginning of flash.... but the binary tell me not.

**Envirement:**

```
System    : Ubuntu14.04.1(4.10.0)
Toolchain : arm-none-eabi-gcc 6.3.1 
Debuger   : Jlink 6.14b + Jlink Debugger 9.20
IDE       : Clion 2017
Other     : Cmake 3.8, uCos II,my ldscript, OZone.
```

Comment: a programs entry and the processors vector table are two different things, the program entry depends on the operating system and what it has defined, you cannot run those applications as if you are booting into them.  Debuggers cause as many problems as they solve perhaps avoid using the debugger in this case.

Comment: that or you simply built the program/project wrong or without a vector table.

Comment: It seems it's a Cortex platform. I see the bootloader example has a stack address (at offset 0x0) at the end of the RAM and the reset vector points to some code in the FLASH, which seems correct. In the other bad "Project", this is not the case. I suspect the makefile compiling the "Project" might lack the linker script. It seems to be using some generic linker value (it's a guess).